# How do I get data into JavaScript and render with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

So here is the situation.  I am originally a PHP developer, here are my steps to render data:

- PHP gather data from DataBase
- PHP write data to JavaScript
- JavaScript render using JQuery to HTML
- HTML display to user
- User Postback to PHP
- PHP write back to Database with new data

Now I am using VB.NET and I need to use their paradigm with controls and what not.  However I would like to render using JQuery and JavaScript.  How do I get data into JavaScript when loaded in VB and get it back once user post?

- VB gather data from DataBase
- ???? (NEED HELP HERE:  How does VB write data to JavaScript in this step)
- JavaScript render using JQuery to HTML
- HTML display to user
- ???? (NEED HELP HERE:  How does user Postback to VB in this step)
- VB write back to Database with new data

Now, I know I can create my own control and write custom render function, but that would take way too long and so this solution is out.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "VB.NET: ". That's what tags are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - have we not automated that yet???  :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: some of it, like [VB.NET]. Not all.

Comment: @John - well thanks for helping make the site a bit cleaner.  After a few more upvotes I'm looking forward to helping out with the mod queue.  Part of me is scared to see what's in there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ???? (NEED HELP HERE: How does VB write data to JavaScript in this
> step)
>
> ???? (NEED HELP HERE: How does user Postback to VB in this step)

The answer to both questions really depends on the specific situation you are in. You can use methods on [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) if you want to spit out pure javascript code on your page. The 2 most useful methods are `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `RegisterStartupScript`

Or, the approach I would follow if you are using JQuery + Ajax, would be to implement WebServices that return data in JSON format. [This blog](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) has very good examples of how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know about those approaches, I will look into them.

Comment: Is there anyway to get data back from the client when using the ClientScriptManager?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu: That's when Page_Methods or Web Services come into play. You can check this: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm for an example on how to call a Page Method from javascript. It's pretty straight forward, basically is just a line of code: `<script>function(){PageMethods.Page_Method_Name("some parameter");}</script>`. Since you are familiar with jQuery, I would look the examples on the blog I linked on my answer. I am more than happy to provide an example from my own code but I really think Encosia's blog does a far better job that I can do.

Comment: Looks good, I went with the example in the Blog you posted.  Out of all the method, this is got to be the easiest.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, here's how you would emit script via asp.net

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
     "someKeyUniqueForThisType", 
     "function add(x, y) { return x + y; }", true);
```

<sub>I'm not certain of the VB translation, but I think this === me (or my?), and as I recall you have to add a _ when you break lines in vb</sub>

This will insert your script function right after the `<form>` tag.  If you want to insert script at a point where your dom is ready, you can use `RegisterStartupScript` which will insert the script right before your `</form>` tag     [reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/902895.aspx)

Note that the final true parameter indicates that script tags need to be added.  If you're adding script tags yourself, then set this to false.

On the second part of your question, the most common way is to either create a static (shared in VB?) method in your code behind, or an asmx webmethod, decorated with the ScriptMethod attribute.  Either can be posted to via jQuery's $.ajax function.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more on how to get data back?  What is ASMX and how does static in VB help with the situation?

Comment: asmx is (essentially) what web services are called in .net.  If you create a web service, any web methods therein which you decorate with [ScriptMethod] can be called from JavaScript using jQuery's $.ajax function.  If you don't feel like creating a web service, you can also just create a static method in your code behind, and post to that instead.  But it has to be static (shared)